# ios sdk URL filename, remove the url addon special character "\"

Tags: ios, swift, url, character

In iOS sdk (swift). Lets say i have a three files "mary'sCat.mp3", "mary\s.mp3", "mary\\s.mp3"
(the special character \ is part of the real filename)
When I use the below code to get the urls

```
FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDir, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
```

and use the below code to get filename

```
fileUrl.standardizedFileURL.lastPathComponent
```

I will have "mary\'sCat.mp3", "mary\\s.mp3", "mary\\\\s.mp3"
So.. is there any way i can remove the system addon special characters \ in a correct way? so i can get back to original file name "mary'sCat.mp3", "mary\s.mp3", "mary\\s.mp3"? I noticed that when using XCode output window you wont see the addon special character, but when you actually see it in debug watch, u will see the addon special character. That is nightmare when doing String compare as below

```
let mediaUrl_filename = "mary\\s.mp3" \\<-- this value from url
let db_filename = "mary\s.mp3" \\ <-- this value from sqlite
if mediaUrl_filename == db_filename {
  print("It is equal")
}
```

So is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually '\' is used as escape sequence in String objects so while comparing the file name if the file name is 'mary\s.mp3' you will have to write like this

```
if mediaUrl_filename == "mary\\s.mp3"{
  print("It is equal")
}
```

I suggest that you replace the '\' with other character like '_' in the file name to ignore such confusions.

Comment: Sorry for some confusion and typo, i updated the question. The problem is the db_filename retrieve from the sqlite directly. If using your method, I also have to do the addon special character on the db_filename, make the value from "mary\s.mp" to "mary\\s.mp", then make the comparison, so both variables with addon special character.

Comment: I can create a URL object by init the sqlite return result "mary\s.mp3", then get the lastPathComponent to make it become "mary\\s.mp3". But I am doing 5000 records here, and looping each filename of 300. So the cost is high as 5000x300 creations. This background task is looping for every 20 sec

Comment: When you get the file name from the sqlite in the String object the extra \ is already going to be added so you can compare as shown in the answer.